# Security through facebook login in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, security, cakephp, authentication

I receive my user's facebook informations from php through the api :
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Is it safe enough to only save the facebook's user id in the database given in php or should i check this user identity from a token or  any kind of password ?

Knowing that i can get all my user's informations in javascript and anyone can set it

Is it safe enough to loggin my facebook's user only thanks to the facebook's data return in php.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused with your quesion because you are using facebook's php sdk so all the user data recieved from facebook is on the server and not in the browser, so how is it possible for an intruder to update from JS? I think you have got it a bit wrong there.

In similar situations i read the data in php get all the necessary details store it in my users table along with the facebook token (mainly the email id). I didnt find much use of the token in my application but just for the sake of it i store it with this done i authenticate the user's session. For the same user logging in again i just check id already in users table and set session.

Comment: Facebook does not send data to any callback URL automatically, unless one has explicitly been set or a subscription to real-time updates has been made. (Or are you talking about canvas/page tab apps, that get a `signed_request` parameter POSTed on initial load into the Facebook iframe …?)

Comment: No i am talking about the facebook oauth api considering the question is about logging a user in via facebook. The login dialog api requires the developer to specify a redirect_uri which is called on clicking the submit on the facebook dialog. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth

The facebook sdk the user is posted is in php itself so i assumed that all the data to and from the facebook server is done on tge server level itself and JS has no role to play.

Comment: That is not a “callback” URL, that is simply what the name says: A URL that the _client_ gets _redirected to_ after showing the OAuth dialog, and therefor it is requested via GET. And all it gets passed are the `code` parameter (for exchange into an access token), and the initially used CSRF value.

Comment: Alright yes we cant call it a callback url. I got it a bit wrong.